# WPF HiercharchicalDataTemplate.DataType: How to react on interfaces?

Tags: wpf, interface, templates, types

#### Problem

I've got a collection of `IThing`s and I'd like to create a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for a `TreeView`. The straightforward `DataType={x:Type local:IThing}` of course doesn't work, probably because the WPF creators didn't want to handle the possible ambiguities.

Since this should handle `IThing`s from different sources at the same time, referencing the implementing class is out of question.

#### Current solution

For now I'm using a ViewModel which proxies IThing through a concrete implementation:

```
public interface IThing {
    string SomeString { get; }
    ObservableCollection<IThing> SomeThings { get; }
    // many more stuff
}

public class IThingViewModel
{
     public IThing Thing { get; }
     public IThingViewModel(IThing it) { this.Thing = it; }
}

<!-- is never applied -->
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:IThing}">

<!-- is applied, but looks strange -->
<HierarchicalDataTemplate
    DataType="{x:Type local:IThingViewModel}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Thing.SomeThings}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Thing.SomeString}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

#### Question

Is there a better (i.e. no proxy) way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that the default template selector supports only concrete types, not interfaces. You need to create a custom DataTemplateSelector and apply it to the ItemTemplateSelector property of the TreeView. I can't find the URL where I found an example of it, but hopefully with this info, you can Google it.

Comment: I guess you mean http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx ? That's probably a good idea!

Comment: @Richard: It doesn't necessarily have to be a *concrete type*. Even abstract types work fine. I had a similar problem and I replaced the IThing interface by AbstractThing abstract class.

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative (similar to jing's solution): If you only have one type of item, you can set the ItemTemplate directly. Then you don't need to set a key or a datatype.

In your ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<IThing> Thingies { get; private set; }
```

In the View:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Thingies}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SomeThings}">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeString}" />    
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is you give a key to the HierarchicalDataTemplate and put it in the Windows.Resources, and manually reference to it in the TreeView.     `<TreeView  ItemDataTemplate={StaticResource templateKey}/>`

But that limits the autoselection of data template according to data type, which is provided by WPF TreeView.